# Spring and Hibernate: use same entity class and repository from multiple databases (data sources)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource

I would like to save data to multiple databases. At this time I have about 800 users and each user has about 500MB of data in database.

**My idea:**

It will be great to create one database for each user. If I need to do something with user `user_123` I can only do it on database `user_123` and one row in share database `main_database`.

[image]

[image]

But how can I implement entity and controler?

For example:

entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="data")
@NamedQuery(name="Data.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Data d")
public class Data implements Serializable {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="value")
    private int data;   

    //...
}
```

dao:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import example.net.entity.Data;

@Repository
public class DataDaoImpl implements DataDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void save(Data data) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(data);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Data> findAll() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Data").list();
    }

    @Override
    public Data findById(int id) {
        return (Data) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Data.class, id);
    }        
}
```

visitor call url **http://example.net/user/123/values** and I need to return all values for `user_123` from database `user_123` table `data` - name of db will be in `main_database`.

I will add a lot of users. Is possible use new databases *dynamically* without define it in `jdbc.properties`? :

```
jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/abc
jdbc.username=abc
jdbc.password=abc
```

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: There are two things you could look into: sharding your data not by user but by some other criteria so that in the end every user only has five databases with 100mb instead. That solves your problem, if you can shard. Your way is the harder one and it's one of the use cases of multi tenancy. Saw a good question about it just the other day...

Comment: Well, that sounds like an absolutely terrible idea. First thing that comes to my mind is reconnection cost. And 500 MB of data per user? How? The whole database design sounds broken.